# Error when debug Ruby on rails by Rubymine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging, rubymine

I have a mistake when I'm try debug Ruby on rails by Rubymine.

[image: debug Ruby on rails by Rubymine]
And my rails file. 
[image]

I don't know why my rails file cannot loaded.

- Ruby version 2.3.3.
- Rails version 5.1.6

Please help me!
Thanks very much!

Comment: I would recommend retrying with a local path that does not include Unicode characters to rule that out. For example, move your app to `C:\ruby\project` and try again. The combination of using Windows, Ruby, and RubyMine opens up a lot of potential incompatibilities when using Unicode characters.

Comment: It worked. Thanks so much :)